# Deadlock appearing intermittently in mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa, database-deadlocks

I am running a multiple spring boot micro-services. All my services connect to database using spring-data(JPA repositories). Unfortunately due to particular API, deadlocks are occurring in database server. As per the primary investigation I feel the deadlock has happened because two transactions trying to modify the same table resource. Should any of it do with isolation levels of transaction.

Yet, I am not able to make concrete conclusion out of it. Can someone please figure out the root cause of this deadlock?

Please see the attached database logs of transactions leading to deadlock in below pictures.

[Transaction1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw9Hy.png)

[Transaction2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWC4O.png)

Comment: Please paste the pictures as text, not as pictures. Nevertheless, altough the answer is "yes, the deadlock has happened because two transactions trying to modify the same table resource", without seeing the relevant code, we cannot really tell you how to fix it, so you would need to add the code for those transactions.

Comment: No, deadlocks do not happen simply because two transactions are trying to modify the same record. That would be taken care of locks. Deadloacks occur because the two transactions  hold locks that prevent the other transaction to proceed and release the locks the first one need to proceed, therefore none of them can proceed. Intermittent deadlocks are fine, you should prepare your application to handle such cases by re-running the transactions again. Regular deadlocks are not fine as these are indicators of poor database / process design.